# Не могу создать базу данных через Java

Tags: jdbc, java, база-данных

Всем привет, подскажите решение моей проблемы, я пытаюсь через `JTextField` передать название базы данных что бы выполнилась команда `create database + name`
Вот класс фрейма где вводится имя БД пароль логин и путь)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package frame;

import bd.DB;
import bd.WorkDB;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author teacher
 */
public class StartFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton createDB, connectDB, deleteDB;
    private JTextField tflogin, tfpath, tfdbname;
    private JPasswordField tfpass;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel login, path, pass, dbname;
    private static String slogin, spath, spass, sNAME;

    public static String getDBNAME() {
        return sNAME;
    }

    public static void setsNAME(String sNAME) {
        StartFrame.sNAME = sNAME;
    }

    public static String getLogin() {
        return slogin;
    }

    public static void setSlogin(String slogin) {
        StartFrame.slogin = slogin;
    }

    public static String getPass() {
        return spass;
    }

    public static void setSpass(String spass) {
        StartFrame.spass = spass;
    }

    public static String getPath() {
        return spath;
    }

    public static void setSpath(String spath) {
        StartFrame.spath = spath;
    }

    public StartFrame() {
        setTitle("start");
        setBounds(150, 150, 290, 270);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponent();
        action();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void initComponent() {
        dbname = new JLabel("Имя базы данных:");
        tfdbname = new JTextField("Internet");

        createDB = new JButton("Создать ДБ");
        deleteDB = new JButton("Уадалить ДБ");
        connectDB = new JButton("Подсоединиться");
        tflogin = new JTextField("root");
        tfpath = new JTextField("jdbc:mysql://localhost/");
        tfpass = new JPasswordField("Generic");
        login = new JLabel("Логин: ");
        pass = new JLabel("Пароль: ");
        path = new JLabel("Путь:");
        panel = new JPanel(null);

        dbname.setBounds(20, 20, 150, 20);
        tfdbname.setBounds(140, 20, 120, 20);
        deleteDB.setBounds(142, 190, 120, 20);
        connectDB.setBounds(150, 142, 100, 20);
        createDB.setBounds(20, 190, 120, 20);

        tflogin.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tfpass.setBounds(150, 120, 100, 20);
        tfpath.setBounds(60, 70, 200, 20);

        login.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 20);
        pass.setBounds(150, 100, 100, 20);
        path.setBounds(20, 70, 100, 20);

        panel.add(dbname);
        panel.add(tfdbname);
        panel.add(tfpath);
        panel.add(path);
        panel.add(pass);
        panel.add(login);
        panel.add(tfpass);
        panel.add(tflogin);
        panel.add(createDB);
        panel.add(connectDB);
        panel.add(deleteDB);
        add(panel);
    }

    public void action() {
        createDB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (tfpath.getText().equals("jdbc:mysql://localhost/")) {
                        if (tflogin.getText().equals("root")) {
                            if (tfpass.getText().equals("Generic")) {                 
                                WorkDB.createDB(tfpath.getText(), tfdbname.getText(), tflogin.getText(), tfpass.getText());
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "База данных создана успешно!", "Создание БД", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный пароль!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный логин", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный путь к БД", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, ex, "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
        });

        deleteDB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent s) {
                try {
                    if (tfpath.getText().equals("jdbc:mysql://localhost/")) {
                        if (tflogin.getText().equals("root")) {
                            if (tfpass.getText().equals("Generic")) {
                                WorkDB.deleteDB(tfpath.getText(), tfdbname.getText(), tflogin.getText(), tfpass.getText());

                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "База данных удалена успешно!", "Удаление БД", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный пароль!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный логин", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный путь к БД", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        connectDB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (tfpath.getText().equals("jdbc:mysql://localhost/")) {
                    if (tflogin.getText().equals("root")) {
                        if (tfpass.getText().equals("Generic")) {
                            spath = tfpath.getText();
                            slogin = tflogin.getText();
                            spass = tfpass.getText();
                            sNAME = tfdbname.getText();
                            new LoginFrame();
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный пароль!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный логин", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Неверный путь к БД", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

                //dispose();
            }
        });

    }
}[/code]

А вот класс где должно всё выполнятся , самое интересное если в этом классе задать константой название то всё ок, но дело в том что мне надо что бы можно было выбирать название, ну это же логично, я просто уже почти доделал проект, и вот такие мелочи не могу сделать(( очень обидно!!!
[code]
package bd;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class WorkDB {
    public static void createDB(String path, String NAME, String login, String pass)

throws SQLException {
        DB db = new DB(path, NAME, login, pass);
        db.update("create database "+NAME);
        db.close();
        db = new DB(path, NAME, login, pass);
        db.update("create table user(Login varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY, Password varCHAR(25))");
        db.update("INSERT INTO user VALUES('As','As')");
        db.update("create table Product(id int (10)  primary KEY, Name varchar(30), Price double(6,2))");
        db.update("INSERT INTO Product VALUES('0','IPhone 6','799.3')");
        db.update("create table blackNote(Login varchar(25) primary key)");
        db.update("create table orders(id_order int(5) auto_increment primary key, number varchar(30), id int(10), phone varchar(30))");
        db.update("create tabe id's(id_orders int(10) auto_increment, id_product(10)");
        db.close();
    }

    public static void deleteDB(String path,String NAME, String login, String pass) throws SQLException {
        DB db = new DB(path, "", login, pass);
        db.update("drop database " + NAME);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

А вот ошибка!!

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'internet'

Comment: Может, ошибка в этом моменте:

throws SQLException {
        // создаем объект БД используя имя NAME, но БД с таким
        // именем еще не существует
        DB db = new DB(path, NAME, login, pass);
        db.update("create database "+NAME);

Я сам еще только учусь и этого вопроса не касался, так что могу и ошибаться...

Comment: А ответ, возможно, кроется в следующей части кода:

    public static void deleteDB(String path,String NAME, 
            String login, String pass) throws SQLException {
        DB db = new DB(path, "", login, pass);    //похоже на решение проблемы
        db.update("drop database " + NAME);
        db.close();
    }